# C# TcpClient cannot reconnect after netwotk unplugged

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient, reconnect

The client cannot reconnect to server after network unplugged and plugged again until stop and start client side service again. I get the following exception:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

after plugging in again.

Also I can't close the stream because `tcpClient` is `null`.

This is connection code:

```
private void BeginConnect()
{
    try
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(this.serverIP, this.serverPort);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //i get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" here
        Disconnect();
    }
}

public void Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
        tcpClient.Client.Disconnect(false);
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        ; // exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    }
    tcpClient = null;
}
```

How can I force close and create a new connection without restarting service?

Comment: `tcpClient` cannot become `null` unless your code changes it to `null`. So it sounds like `Disconnect()` has already been called. It *should* be that calling `BeginConnect` lets it all back connect, unless there is some socket throttling in place...

Comment: Do you properly refresh `this.serverIP` and `this.serverPort` after the reconnect? Did you hook into [NetworkChange Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange_events(v=vs.110).aspx) and properly refresh your endpoints and DNS cached lookups?

Comment: Thanks for reply, now i check null for tcpClient so it runs just one time. But i can't still reconnect. After plug the cable again i get error: (target machine actively refused it). What should i do when ping response is false? I mean calling Disconnect method is required or not?

Comment: Remus how can i do that? I use .Net 3.5